# Cesium TaskProcessor vs Web Worker

Tags: web-worker, cesiumjs

I need to process a large amount of data.  I was wondering if there are any reasons to use Cesium's TaskProcessor rather than a typical Web Worker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cesium's [TaskProcessor](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/TaskProcessor.html?classFilter=taskprocessor) wraps the existing Web Worker system to return a `Promise`.  Cesium uses an internal copy of the `when.js` library to manage asynchronous activities with promises.  Cesium also takes some [extra steps](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.26/Source/Core/TaskProcessor.js#L52-L56) to determine if `TypedArrays` transfer correctly from web workers, as some browsers have issues there.  `TypedArrays` are needed for transferring data to WebGL, such as vertex data, and Cesium uses TaskProcessors to prepare some of this data outside of the main UI thread.

Comment: Browser issues aside, any reason to use one over the other for processing data?

Comment: Scott H already answered that with "no" on the thread you link to in your answer.  I believe Scott is the original/primary author of TaskProcessor, so I would take his word.

Answer (score 1):

This question is discussed here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/m0KjGPE6zDY